# If $\tan A+\tan B+\tan C=6$ and $\tan A\tan B=2 $ in $\triangle ABC$, then find the type of triangle.

Tags: trigonometry

> In $\triangle ABC$, $\tan A+\tan B+\tan C=6 \\
> \tan A\tan B=2
> $
>
> Then the triangle is

$a.)\text{Right-angled isosceles} \\
 b.) \text{Acute-angled isosceles}\\
\color{green}{c.)\text{Obtuse-angled}} \\
 d.)\text{equilateral} $

$\ \ \ $

$\tan A+\tan B+\tan C=6 \\
\tan A\tan B=2 \\
A+B=180-C\\
\dfrac{\tan A+\tan B}{1-\tan A\tan B}=-\tan C\\
\tan A+\tan B=\tan C\\
\tan C=3 \\
\tan A\tan B=2\ \text{and} \ \tan A+\tan B=3  \\
\implies \tan A=2, \tan B=1\ \ \text{or}\ \  \tan A=1, \tan B=2
 $

Now I am stucked, I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths upto $12$th grade .

Note:- Calculator is not allowed.

Comment: If $\tan(A)\tan(B) = 2$ (a positive) then $A$ and $B$ must be acute...meaning you only need to see whether or not $\tan(C)$ is negative (i.e. $C$ is obtuse).  It cannot possibly be a right triangle since $\tan(A)$, $\tan(B)$, and $\tan(C)$ must all be defined ($\tan(90^\circ)$ is undefined since $\cos(90^\circ) = 0$).

Answer (score 5):

For any triangle, we have
$$\tan(A) + \tan(B) + \tan(C) = \tan(A) \tan(B) \tan(C)$$
This means we have
$$\tan(A) \tan(B) \tan(C) = 6$$
Hence, we have $\tan(C) = 3$. Hence, we have
$$\tan(A) + \tan(B) = 3 \text{ and }\tan(A) \tan(B) = 2$$
This gives us that $\tan(A) = 2$ and $\tan(B) = 1$. Hence, the triangle is an acute angled triangle with one angle being $\dfrac{\pi}4$ and others being $\arctan(2)$ and $\arctan(3)$.

Comment: Well, knowing that fact would have made my answer much simpler...

Comment: ...also, with that fact, right away you _know_ that the triangle must be acute since $\tan(A)\tan(B)\tan(C)$ must be negative to be obtuse (since there can only be one obtuse angle).

Answer (score 0):

You have done the hard work

As $0<\tan A,\tan B,\tan C<\infty$

$0<A,B,C<\dfrac\pi2$

As $\tan A,\tan B,\tan C$ are distinct, so will be $A,B,C$

Comment: So as in option $a,\ b,\ $ and $d.$ at least $2$ angles are similar , hence option $c.$ is correct by rejecting other options?

Comment: @RK, Why $b$ suggests " at least 22 angles are similar" ?

Answer (score 0):

WLOG, $C = \tan^{-1}(3) \approx 72^{\circ}, A = \tan^{-1}(1) = 45^{\circ}, B = \tan^{-1}(2) \approx 63^{\circ}$. This shows that $\triangle ABC$ is scalene !